# Quantum Maxwell Demon by Zurek

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

I just recently started on my bachelor thesis concerning the exorcism of Maxwell's demon. I'm planning to review some of the historical papers in order to capture the demons joyful journey in the thesis. 
While I'm now at the point where I'm  mostly clear about what I want to discuss in detail and which final solution I want to present, there are still plenty obscurities in the detailed derivations of results in the historic papers, eg. "[Maxwell's demon, Szilard's engine and quantum
measurements](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301076)", by WH Zurek.

I really like his approach to the matter, and how the comes up with the two-well potential, causing the energy degeneracy. His final solution, the demon mixed state at the end of the cycle, is imho a sound argument in consistency with Landauer's principle. But when it comes to the quantum measurement (sec IV), i find it rather hard to follow his notation.

First, he definies a joint density Matrix $P$ from $\tilde{\rho}$ and The pure demon State $\vert D_0 \rangle \langle D_0 \vert$ , Which is itself a superposition of the possible outcomes $\vert D_R \rangle$ and $\vert D_L \rangle$. But I cant follow him in neglecting small off-diagonal terms, which lead him to

$P=\exp \big( -i H_{int} \Delta t/ \hbar \big) \tilde{\rho} \vert D_0 \rangle \langle D_0 \vert \big) \approx \tfrac{1}{2} \big( \rho_L \vert D_L \rangle \langle D_L \vert + \rho_R \vert D_R \rangle \langle D_R\vert \big)\quad\quad \tag{24}$

I think this approximation is crucial for the next step, where he defines the mutual information of subsystem A, B (resp. gas and demon) by the joint matrix $P$, the gas matrix $\tilde{\rho}$ and the demon matrix $\rho_D$. The measurement is thus achieved by the transistion from $P$ over $\Delta t$ to the form stated in the above formula, where the gas matrix is to be constant afterwards, but the demon matrix will be in a  mixed state, the final reason for the entropy increase. But I don't see how he identifies $\tilde{\rho}$ with $\rho_G$ in Eq. 30 and argues that it is constant over $\Delta t$

So, if there are any of you familiar with the paper or the topic, I'm really looking forward to your answers!

Comment: I am neither an expert nor have I read the paper, so this is a wild guess / brain fart, but one avenue might be that this is a place where Zurek (implicitly) exploits his famous approach to decoherence (the product of sines thing)? Is there anything implicit in the paper about the structure of the Hamiltonian wrt the outcome states, pointer states, etc?